# Update collection inside autorun without rerun (Meteor.JS)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I trying to find best practies how can we update collection inside tracker authorun;

For example i want to update count of views in my collection. But i wanna be sure my subscription is ready and i have object for work;

For example in onCreated section:

```
 var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        var topicId = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
        self.subscribe('Topic', topicId);
        if(self.subscriptionsReady()){
          //  var topic = Topic.findOne(topicId);
          //  topic.upViews();
        }
    });
```

This code will goes in infinite loop, because our commented out code will change object. How best to do in this case ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a pretty good way (may be not).
We can update a collection with **nonreactive** Tracker function();

```
var self = this;
self.autorun(function() {
    var topicId = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    self.subscribe('Topic', topicId);
    if(self.subscriptionsReady()){
      Tracker.nonreactive(function(){
        var topic = Topic.findOne(topicId);
        topic.upViews();
      })
  }
});
```

I think that 's it. Maybe someone will offer better?
If no offer version is better , I 'll close the question in a day

Comment: That's pretty much the way to do it.

Comment: @MichelFloyd hello! Thank you!